# Android: seems to "scaletype" is ignored, when add more then 1 ImageView to a FrameLayout?

Tags: android, imageview, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout and want to add 2 ImageViews on top of each other. 
This is my code

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams ImageViewParams = new     
FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, param_height);                                                              

            ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
                mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                mImageView.setImageResource(mImageArray[counter]);
                mImageView.setLayoutParams(ImageViewParams);
            ImageView mImageView2 = new ImageView(getActivity());
                mImageView2.setBackgroundResource(mImageArray[counter]);
                mImageView2.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                mImageView2.setLayoutParams(ImageViewParams);

            FrameLayout mFrameLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
            mFrameLayout.addView(mImageView);

            if(counter != 0)
            mFrameLayout.addView(mImageView2);
```

mImageView2 is stretched. It seems to that "scaleType" is ignored? The FrameLayout is in a TableLayout. The TableLayout gets populated in a for Loop...

Answer (score 2):

My Mistake!
I used "setBackgroundResource" instead of "setImageResource" for mImageView2. Maybe this help someone...